# How to change text style on tap of a Card?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

How do I strikethrough the text in the card and change the text's color when I tap the card. Thank You. Here is the code:

```
Widget _buildTodoItem(String title) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(16.0, 16.0, 16.0, 0.0),
      child: GestureDetector(
        onTap: () => , //here
        child: Card(
          child: Container(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
            child: Text(title),
          ),
        ),
    ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

**Screenshot:**

[image]

---

**Code:**

```dart
bool _enabled = true;
  
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    body: Center(
      child: Card(
        child: InkWell(
          onTap: () => setState(() => _enabled = !_enabled),
          child: Container(
            width: 100,
            height: 100,
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            child: Text(
              'Click me',
              style: TextStyle(decoration: _enabled ? null : TextDecoration.lineThrough),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: Thank You, it worked wonders. How do i change the text color

Comment: You can change it in `TextStyle` by setting `color` property.

Comment: @meltdown_ultra: consider accepting the answer if you found it helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create a `bool` to check whether the card has actually been tapped :

```dart
onTap:(){
 setState((){
  isTapped=!isTapped;
 })
}
child: Card(
          child: Container(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
            child: Text(title, style: TextStyle(decoration: isTapped ?TextDecoration.lineThrough : null)),
          ),
        ),
```

Comment: When using your code it creates multiple other errors

Comment: Yes the `setState` was missing a `()`.

Comment: oh ok, that makes sense